# Wiring multiple 5.2 V Li-ion booster modules outputs together to get 3 A output current

Tags: voltage-regulator, raspberry-pi, battery-operated, 18650

I need help figuring out how to wire booster modules in parallel for a high current output. I'm using four 18650 batteries to power a tablet I'm putting together that runs on a Raspberry Pi 4, and unfortunately the 5.1 V, 3 A power requirement has proved difficult to satisfy.

I can't find a lithium battery circuit that provides the full 3 A, only 2.5 A, and the ones I've found are expensive and usually sold through eBay or Amazon, which I'm not inclined to trust with the now expensive Pi 4 8G.

My solution is to power the device through several 5.2 V, 1 A modules I got off of Adafruit ([MiniBoost](https://www.adafruit.com/product/4654) 5 V @ 1 A - TPS61023) wired in parallel.

From what I've read, simply wiring them in parallel would cause the synchronous rectifier MOSFETs to 'fight', resulting in a single module taking up the entire load. The fixes I've found result in less regulation, voltage drop, current-sharing issues, and so on. How do I wire these in parallel without diverging from the power requirement?

The Pi 4b needs a power supply that can provide at least 3 A and 4.75-5.25 V.

Comment: If you're using 4 batteries, why not wire them in a 2x2 array, so you've got a voltage >5V and you can then look for a step-down regulator? Do you need to use off-the-shelf components? Then can you not just buy a charging bank with the required output?

Comment: I could wire the batteries in series, but I've already got tp4056 modules wired in, and I could also wire the booster modules in series to get a similar effect. But, I'd then need to find a reputable module that can carry 3A, and some form of isolation to protect my pi if the module fails. I'd like it if I can find a solution that doesn't involve more spending and more frustration. I can do this if I have to, though.

Comment: You can get a power bank from the PI hut which should give you a measure of confidence that it won't break the PI, and at least that'll be a guaranteed fix. You'll have to spend some money, even if just on components to do the power-sharing.

Comment: Ok, I'll check that out. Thanks for the help :)